# How to install Tensorflow GPU on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, nvidia

I am using AWS P2 gpu instance with Tesla K80 GPU and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Installing Tensorflow for CPU is easy:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

But Installing Tensorflow for GPU doesnt work :

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatically Install all recommended ubuntu drivers ( which includes nvidia driver):

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*     
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

You will be asked to set a password to verify that the install is genuine. after you set that password, reboot your computer. Then dont start in normal mode, go to MOK mode and enter that password as the key. 
Once you reboot (restart) , check if drivers are installed successfully by:

```
nvidia-smi
```

Then Install Anaconda  [link](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/Install-TensorFlow-with-GPU-Support-the-Easy-Way-on-Ubuntu-18-04-without-installing-CUDA-1170/) which will take care of everything.

Answer (score 4):

#### Installing Nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia* && sudo apt autoremove  
sudo reboot  # you will have to wait till reboot completes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
curl -O http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo dpkg -i ./cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda-9-0
```

#### following code should show you details about your gpu

```
nvidia-smi
```

#### if you see details about your GPU, continue with following commands

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/open-source-william-falcon/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.1.tgz  
sudo tar -xzvf cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.1.tgz  
sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64"
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
source ~/.bashrc
```

#### Make sure to uninstall your previous Tensorflow. Then activate your virtual env and install tensorflow_gpu in it. If you dont have a virtual env (you should) , following code will help you:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
mkdir ~/virtualenv #creating a folder to store all your virtual env
cd ~/virtualenv/
virtualenv -p python3 venv1 #creates venv1 with new python installed on your ubuntu
source venv1/bin/activate #activates your venv
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
pip install jupyter # coz i like jupyter
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

#### now lets test if Tensorflow-gpu works

```
python
import tensorflow as tf   
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!') #if no error received, its working
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices() #this will show all CPU's and GPU's on your system
```

#### yay!!

Comment: I get this: 
 tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64